# .htaccess redirect index.php to /

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-fcgid

I would like to hide the index.php page and just show the domain.

Is this possible with .htaccess?

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```

Also tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9} /index.php HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

index.php still shows

Answer (score 11):

Try, It works for me!  Make sure your have `AllowOverride All` set in httpd.conf

```
RewriteEngine On 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

There is a regex issue in your rules, I have modified your rules and it works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example\.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index\.php [L]
```

Comment: nope. could browsers always show the index.php and not redirect to just the domain?

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess file.

Comment: the redirect is working, but also adding an trailing slash, the result is example.com// instead of example.com

Answer (score 6):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(html|php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite '/index.php' through .htaccess like this:

```
# Remove /index.php from all urls
RewriteRule ^(.+)/index\.php$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```